# siunitx - Underline significant digits in SI object

Tags: siunitx, underline

## Context

Hello all,

I am writing a document making use of the `siunitx` package for my unit formatting. I use the `\SI{...}{...}` blocks for ease of writing when formatting my numbers.

In my document, I need to be able to specify the significant digits of my numbers. The convention I am following is to have the least-significant digit underlined and to have extra digits following it, like so:

[image: A number: 7.9420*10^-2 g, where the 4 is underlined]

Currently, I produce this with the code:

```tex
= 7.9\underline{4}20 \times 10^{-2} \, \si{\gram}
```

This code is unwieldy and I would like to produce the example number just using an `\SI{...}{...}` block. However, I am unable to find any way to make `siunitx` underline a specific digit in the `\SI{...}{...}` block input. An example of how I would like to use the `\SI{...}{...}` block to specify the given number might be:

```tex
= \SI{7.9_4_20e-2}{\gram}
```

## Question

I am wondering two things:

- Does `siunitx` provide a built-in way to underline digits in `\SI{...}{...}` blocks?
- If not, does `siunitx` provide a way to customize the parser for `\SI{...}{...}` blocks so that I could implement the digit underline mechanism myself?

## Research

I have looked over the `siunitx` manual but the closest I could find to underlined significant digits is `siunitx`'s uncertainty mechanism. However, this formats uncertainty by having the uncertainty located in parenthesis or after a `\pm` at the end of the number. This is not what I need.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I guess that `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{7.9\underline{4}20\times10^{-2}}{\gram}` is not much of an improvement from your point of view.

Comment: @Mico sadly this also interferes with the `e-2` power-of-ten mechanism meaning that I have to type everything the same way I would have to normally. If there were a way to simply ask `siunitx` to accept the `\underline{...}` in an otherwise normally parsed environment, that might work.

Comment: I don't think anything like this is supported by `siunitx`, as printing non-significant digits doesn't make much sense. At least I've never come across a context where it does. You'll have to build you own macro if you need it.

Comment: Also note that you should switch to `\qty` instead of `\SI` when using new versions of `siunitx`.